# Java Sockets Concurrency Threads Being Too Slow

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, synchronized

I am developing an application in Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1 and I receive data from a Socket. This application acts as a Listener and once data is received it is processed. This application was single threaded and due to it processing it slowly, the application is implemented using Threads which is now a multi threaded application. By doing this, the application now runs much faster.

However, there are two threads and both threads access the database to insert and update the database. I face the problem of concurrency where one thread inserts and the other updates causing problems. To deal with concurrency, I added a synchronized block to lock an object making sure the full block is executed. By doing this application is now very slow as it was with a single threaded application. The insert and update is done through JDBC.

Is there anything else that can be done so it is processed and processed very quickly without slowing down the application. The below is sample code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Listener {

     private ServerSocket serverSocket;
     private Socket socket;
     private Object object;
     private InetAddress server;
     @Resource
     private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
          object = new Object();
          serverSocket = new ServerSocket("somePortNumber");
          Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 checkDatabase();
                 if(!isServerActive()) {
                    // send e-mail
                    listen();
                 }
                 else {
                    listen();
                 }
              }
          };
          executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }

     public void listen() {
           if(socket == null) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
           }
           else if(socket.isClosed()) {
                 socket = serverSocket.accept();
           }
           startThread(socket);
     }

     public void startThread(Socket socket) {
           Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                   processMessage(socket);
              }
           };
           new Thread(runnable).start();
     }

     public void processMessage(Socket socket) {
          synchronized(object) {
              // build data from Socket
              // insert into database message, sentDate
              // do other things
              // update processDate
         }
     }

   public void checkDatabase() {
        synchronized(object) {
            // get data and further update
        }
   }

  public boolean isServerActive() {
      boolean isActive = true;
      if(server == null) {
            sever = InetAddress.getByName("serverName");
      }
      if(!server.isNotReachable(5000)) {
          isActive = false;
          if(socket != null) {
             socket.close();
          }
      }
      return isActive;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
Table name: Audit

Message: VARCHAR NOT NULL
SentDate: DATE NOT NULL
ProcessedDate: DATE
AnotherDate: DATE

Query: INSERT INTO AUDIT (message, sentDate, processedDate, receivedDate) VALUES (?, java.sql.Timestamp, null, null)
```

Assuming a record is inserted without the synchronized block inserting the message and sentDate. The other thread will execute causing this record to be found and further update. The problem is that after the initial insert and processedDate should be updated and then the other thread should be executed.

The processMessage() sends the data over HTTPS asynchronously.

One of the reasons to use Threads was because only one piece of data came to Java. So by introducing threads the full set of data comes to Java.

Comment: So your concurrency problem was the database, not the threading. I suggest you post details of the table, the insert, and the query.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Even with single thread you can get much better speed by using JDBC batching and running any transactions around the batch instead of committing every individual insert/update statement.

In a multi threaded environment you can avoid concurrency problems if you ensure no two threads act on the same database row at the same time. You can use row level locks to avoid multiple threads updating the same row.

It is not possible to give you any more inputs with the information you have given. You may get more ideas if you provide information about the data you are processing.

Comment: Can row level locks be implemented in Java through JDBC? The data is messages coming in. I can't really give any detail of the message but there are customer records coming in some defined format. The problem is that I can't use JDBC batching because the application is ayshcnronous. Meaning that when a data is received it is processed and sent through HTTPS in a aysnchrnonous manner.

Comment: @user3189663 Have you been banned from Google? Second link on "JDBC row lock" gives a pretty good guide.

Comment: Sorry to say that I can't give you any more inputs with the available information.

Comment: What do you mean by the second link. Could you attach the link please?

Comment: The second link that I get is http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop71.html from Google. It would be helpful you could post the link.

Comment: @user3189663 [Blog](http://blog.udby.com/archives/15). It doesn't say anything out of the ordinary - isolation, updatable result sets and "SELECT * FOR UPDATE" do the trick, but depends on your DB

Answer (score 0):

The application behaved as single threaded because the processMessage & checkDatabase methods have  synchronised block on the same class object , the threads that are listening currently will hold the  lock and other threads will have to wait until the message is processed,which will cause the application to slow down. instead of putting synchronised in two separate blocks create separate threads outside of the class that checks this condition and try to invoke then separately based on a condition or you could try with wait() and notifyAll in your synchronized blocks also.

Comment: I don't exactly get when you mean. Could you give an example code to show this?

Comment: Could you tell me how the condition is set?

Comment: Please see edit above. I have added some more code. The code shows the condition set.